# Compiling Fails with CS0452 Error Under VS 2015

Tags: c#, generics, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

I have some code that creates a typed value from a string representation. This code handles value types, classes, arrays, etc.

Unfortunately, after upgrading to VS 2015 code analysis outputs this error when compiling:

> CS0452 The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Foo.Bar(string)'

This error did not occur under VS 2012 or 2013 and the code compiled and worked correctly.

ProfileValue.Value is of type String.
In CreateValue, T may be a value type, class, etc.

Calling code:

```
private static T CreateValue<T>(ProfileValue profileValue)
{
    // setup code
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
    {
        // handle strings specially
    }
    else if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        // handle arrays specially
    }
    else if (typeof(T).IsClass)
    {
        return Foo.Bar<T>(profileValue.Value); // <-- error occurs here
    }
    // additional cases
}
```

Called method signature:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static T Bar<T>(String value) where T : class, new()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This passed code analysis in VS 2013 and works great. What can I do to solve the new VS 2015 code analysis error?

Comment: Code you've show is invalid and can't be compiled with C# 5.0 also. Not sure why you believe `Foo.Bar<T>` can be compiled without `where T:class` on the `CreateValue<T>` method.

Comment: What do you mean by "new CS0452"? The error isn't new to VS2015, and is a real compiler error, not "code analysis". Do you mean it's just "new" for your code? I don't see anything in your code that suggests it would ever have worked. With the constraint on `Bar<T>()`, any callers need a similar constraint if they are generic (and if not, they need to pass a reference type with a parameterless constructor). Change `CreateValue<T>(ProfileValue profileValue)` to `CreateValue<T>(ProfileValue profileValue) where T : class, new()`

Comment: @PeterDuniho I meant new to my code. I tweaked the question title and body slightly to reflect that.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted to suggest it ever should have compiled. Just to make sure I wasn't going senile, I humored your question and copy/pasted the code and attempted to compile it. I get the exact same CS0452 error in VS2013 that you are getting in VS2015. I really don't believe you could ever have compiled the above code in VS2013 without errors. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows a scenario where the code in your question will compile in VS2013 but not in VS2015.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right, the simplistic example code I provided doesn't compile. I stripped out some details for simplicity. One of those details is the call to Foo.Bar has a (dynamic) cast in it like so: return Foo.Bar<T>((dynamic)profileValue.Value); In the simplistic code from above, that still fails to compile but oddly enough works and compiles in the actual source c ode. I'm not sure why that is there or why it would make a difference.

Comment: @PeterDuniho When I remove the (dynamic) cast in the original source, it fails to compile with the same error.

Comment: So, are you saying that in VS2015, even with `dynamic`, you get a _compiler_ error? I.e. you are actually seeing CS0452? Or are you confusing that compiler error with a _code analysis_ error (which would start with `CA`). When you use `dynamic`, you are telling the C# compiler to defer compilation (including type checking) until runtime. If you're getting CS0452, maybe VS2015's removed a loophole in the generic constraint checking. I'm not actually upgraded to VS2015 myself yet, so my ability to experiment with your scenario is limited.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have full code analysis enabled. However, it is listed in the Error List window as CS0452. I'm guessing you are right on VS 2015 having removed a loophole exploited by the presence of a cast to dynamic. This especially makes sense given that a simplified example using dynamic fails in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Code Contracts under VS 2015 fails when code uses dynamic. This is due to the changes in the Roslyn compiler.

https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/18